# Code Generated Objects within a loop, blank duplicates show up before them

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

So I am creating a web page for an audio hire enquiry system. The items are held in a database with info such as Brand, Model, Cost per day, Type etc.

I need to load the webpage with a label, image, button and text box for each item in the database (which will grow and shrink over time).

To do this I query the database to find the total number of items, and then generate and populate the items within this loop (Which is a mix between HTML and C# code blocks); (I have removed some small formatting things such as line breaks etc to make it easier to read)

```
<%     for (int i = 1 ; i <= total; i++)
        {
            brand = getBrand(i, conString);
            name = getName(i, conString);
            price = getPrice(i, conString);
            type = getType(i, conString);   %>

            <asp:Label ID="lblName" CssClass="name" runat="server"/>

        <%  (lblName).Text = (brand + " " + name);
            lblName.ID = "lblName" + i;     %>

            <asp:Image ID="imgItem" runat="server" Width="325px"/>

        <%  imgItem.ImageUrl = (@"~\Images\" + brand + "_" + name + ".jpg");
            imgItem.ID = "imgItem" + i;     %>

            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" CssClass="info" runat="server"/>

        <%  lblPrice.Text = ("£" + Convert.ToString(price) + " per day");
            lblPrice.ID = "lblPrice" + i;   %>

            <asp:Button id="btnAdd"  text="Add" runat="server" onClick="btnAdd_Click"/>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty"  TextMode="Number" Width="24px" CssClass="quantity" runat="server">1</asp:TextBox>

        <%  btnAdd.Load += new EventHandler(btnAdd_Click);
            btnAdd.ID = Convert.ToString(i);
            txtQty.ID = ("txtQty" + i);  %>

            <asp:Image CssClass="rule" runat="server"/>

    <%  }%>
```

However, when it generated the web page, it does not start on the first item, it starts with blank version of the objects before their ID's get changed (eg, btnAdd instead of 1, 2, etc):

[image: Web Page with blank object duplicates]

I've searched all over and cannot find a solution.

-Setting the view state to false in the designer gets rid of all the objects, not just the first ones (which are the only ones that show up in the designer).

-Deleting them from the designer deletes the lines of code, and re-adding the lines of code adds them back to the designer

Any help or anything to point me in the right direction of somewhere that would help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Could you show how you get the data?

Comment: May I suggest a `Repeater` Control? That will make it much easier for you.

Comment: @VDWWD I will take a look, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Is it possible your db does not have IDs that match the value of **i**?

Comment: @StinkyTowel No the ID's match because it find the items to load into the form. If i start the value one higher the blank stays there but the next item is just shifted one ahead

Comment: You're going to run into issues relying on **i** to drive your data lookup.  As   [Ben](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3195552/ben) pointed out, you should use a `repeater` control that will manage the creation of the rows of images/text.  Call your datasource and bind it to the repeater based on what's in the database.  Here's an example that may be helpful: http://codedisplay.com/how-to-bind-datatble-data-into-repeater-control-in-asp-net-c-vb-net/